# Google Sheet Multiple Dependant Dropdowns Using ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create multiple dependant dropdown lists that filter a data set inside Google Sheet.

The "Rate Filter Basic" tab works the way I expect it to, without creating an ArrayFunction to replicate the dropdowns.

The "Rate Table" tab is the data source I'm filtering.

The "Rate Filter Adv" tab is where I'm trying to create an ArrayFormula that will auto populate the deeper levels of the dropdown lists.  I have been learning that not all functions allow me to nest ArrayFormula or AND OR clauses inside them.

The tabs with "*" are where I have rebuilt the dropdown data for each list. "Payments*" has a highlighted cel with the "NEXO" which should not be there.

Where I have come unstuck, is on the "Payment" Dropdown, that is dependant on the first 2 (Service, Token).  On the "Rate Filter Adv" tab, the cel D5 should only have "In-Kind" as a result.  Not In-Kind and NEXO.

I'm open to completely new ways to solve this.
I'm trying everything I can.  Currently looking at QUERY, but I'm working through the ArrayFormula, AND, OR, limitations on that too.

DEMO SHEET

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rcWYgNeAXE8mEb43m0Jf50cQ9U9ntA0yd8znXAi5kMU/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17b0FoUHM5lAOcdeWnzxrGm6ErqYxWlfggcNDsKt8yHQ/edit?usp=sharing
example of formula

```
=transpose(unique(query('Rate Table'!A$4:D,"select D where A='"& 'Rate Filter Adv'!B4 &"' AND B='"& 'Rate Filter Adv'!C4 &"' AND C='"& 'Rate Filter Adv'!D4 &"' ")))
```

When applying a new value in column C or D, you can erase other values with onEdit

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName()=='Rate Filter Adv'){
    var c = rg.getColumn();
    var r = rg.getRow();
    if (c==4){sh.getRange(r,c+1).setValue('')}
    if (c==3){
      sh.getRange(r,c+1).setValue('')
      sh.getRange(r,c+2).setValue('')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it is a nice solution, but it doesn't take the "ArrayFormula" into consideration.

Reason I really wanted that on all of the sub tabs, if I extended the rows down, I wanted to the sub tabs to also auto update the rows downwards.

I just tried to add ArrayFormula myself, but it looks like the QUERY is not supporting it.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: James, I would like to find such a solution ! I tried with FILTER, MMULT and so forth ... the only way I found is to fill sufficient lines in sub tabs once for all.

Comment: No problem.  Thank you.  I'm just going to run with a limited number of rows.